# Wordpress cpt pagination

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pagination

I've got a custom post type plugin that's bringing in all posts via a shortcode. all this works well. I want to be able to paginate through the returned posts with jquery and have tried various ways from online tutorials. The last two days has been painful.

My code is:

```
 function xma_display_stores() {
     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 2;
     $args = array('post_type' = > 'stores', 'orderby' = > 'title', 'order' = > 'asc', 'posts_per_page' = > $paged);
     $success = new WP_Query($args);
     $output = '';
     $output. = sprintf("<table class='stores'>");
     $output. = sprintf("<tr><th>File Name</th><th>Date added</th><th>Download</th></tr>");
     while ($success - > have_posts()) {
         $success - > the_post();
         $output. = sprintf("<tr>");
         $output. = sprintf("<td>%s</td>", get_the_title());
         $output. = sprintf("<td>%s</td>", get_the_date());
         $output. = sprintf("<td>%s</td>", wp_get_attachment_link());
         $output. = sprintf("<tr>");
     }
     $output. = sprintf("</tr></table>");
     $output. = sprintf("<p>%s</p>", next_posts_link('Next set'));
     $output. = sprintf("<p>%s</p>", previous_posts_link('Prev set'));
     return $output;
 }
 add_shortcode('display_stores', 'xma_display_stores');
```

Comment: If you want to paginate with jquery just use DataTables plugin http://datatables.net/

Comment: I don't want to use a plugin - the code itself is in a plugin and I want it to be self contained.

Comment: Can you show us a cap with the output of your plugin, it seems that your Next Set and Prev Set, doesn't work right??

Comment: correct - they don't appear in the output, sure, whats a cap?

Comment: Update the codes of the following functions: next_posts_link and previous_posts_link ...btw a cap it's a screen cap xD

Answer (score 1):

Replace your version of $paged and $args with:

```
 $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
 $args = array( 'post_type' = > 'stores', 'orderby' = > 'title', 'order' = > 'asc', 'paged' => $paged );
```

posts_per_page determines how many posts to show on a page and not which page of posts to show.

Also add $success->max_num_pages as a second argument to next_posts_link so:

```
 $output. = sprintf( "<p>%s</p>", next_posts_link( 'Next set', $success->max_num_pages ) );
```

Comment: Apologies - didn't work after a browser refresh just shows the two stores in the table and no next/prev links at the bottom.

Comment: I also need display 10 stores at a time and not 1

Comment: If you only have two stores and have it set to show 10 per page you'll only see 2. There won't be any prev / next links either because there are no pages to go to. Add 'posts_per_page' => 10 to the array of arguments to show 10 per page if you're default isn't already 10.

Comment: I have over 20 in the cpt stores, I tried adding that to the posts_per_page but each time Next Set is clicked it only retrieves a single store and adds it to the existing. Also the url changes from stores/page/2